# Filling a Tkinter Canvas Polygon with an Image

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to fill a Tkinter canvas polygon with an image using PIL or another libraries? I need to transform an image or draw it by pixel.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a polygon around an image, but you can't fill a polygon with an image. You would have to calculate the space of a polygon, and then use an external library or program to change the size of the image. Tkinter can  only double or halve the size of images.

Comment: What kind of external library can i use?

Comment: Pillow and ImageMagick would be a good starting point for research.

Comment: Can i have example? 
xy_list = [[-50, -50], [-50, 50], [50, 50], [75, 0], [50, -50]]